# Translate XML-tags to fit table columns

Tags: c#, xml

I'm writing a program that maps XML data to a database table.

This is how I tried it:

namespace TESTMAPPNING2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test();
        }

```
    static void Test()
    {
        string connetionString = null;
        SqlConnection connection;
        SqlCommand command;
        SqlDataAdapter adpter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        XmlReader xmlFile;
        string sql = null;

        //The XML-tags that i want to insert in the table columns
        string PersonalIdentityNumber = null;
        //string ProtectedIdentity = null;
        //int ReferedCivicRegistrationNumber = 0;
        //string UnregistrationReason = null;
        //DateTime? UnregistrationDate = null;
        //string MessageComputerComputer = null;
        //int GivenNameNumber = 0;
        //string FirstName = null;
        //string LastName = null;
        //string NotifyName = null;
        //DateTime? NationalRegistrationDate = null;
        //string NationalRegistrationCountyCode = null;
        //string NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode = null;
        //string NationalRegistrationCoAddress = null;
        //string NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1 = null;
        //string NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2 = null;
        //string NationalRegistrationPostCode = null;
        //string NationalRegistrationCity = null;
        //string NationalRegistrationNotifyDistributionAddress = null;
        //string NationalRegistrationNotifyPostCode = null;
        //string NationalRegistrationNotifyCity = null;
        //string ForeignDistrubtionAddress1 = null;
        //string ForeignDistrubtionAddress2 = null;
        //string ForeignDistrubtionAddress3 = null;
        //string ForeignDistrubtionCountry = null;
        //string ForeignDate = null;
        //string BirthCountyCode = null;
        //string BirthParish = null;
        //string ForeignBirthCity = null;
        //string CitizenshipCode = null;
        //DateTime? CitizenshipDate = null;
        //string Email = null;
        //string Telephone = null;
        //string Mobiletelephone = null;
        //string Gender = null;
        //string NotNewsPaper = null;
        //string Note = null;
        //string StatusCode = null;
        //string NationalRegistrationCode = null;
        //DateTime? RegistrationDate = null;
        //DateTime? LastUpdatedFromNavet = null;
        //string TemporaryDistrubtionAddress1 = null;
        //string TemporaryDistrubtionAddress2 = null;
        //string TemporaryDistrubtionAddress3 = null;
        //string TemporaryDistrubtionCountry = null;
        //string Password = null;
        //string VisibilityLevel = null;
        //string LastChangedBy = null;
        //DateTime? LastChangedDate = null;
        //int SeamanIdentity = 0;
        //string Category = null;







        connetionString = "Data Source=tsrv2062;Initial Catalog=Bums;User ID=BumsUser;Password=2tusen7Bums";

        connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

        xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("navetout.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
        ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);

        int i = 0;
        connection.Open();
        for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            PersonalIdentityNumber = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();



            SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Seamen(PersonalIdentityNumber, ProtectedIdentity, ReferedCivicRegistrationNumber, UnregistrationReason, UnregistrationDate, MessageComputerComputer, GivenNameNumber, FirstName, LastName, NotifyName, NationalRegistrationDate, NationalRegistrationCountyCode, NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode, NationalRegistrationCoAddress, NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1, NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2, NationalRegistrationPostCode, NationalRegistrationCity ) values(@PersonalIdentityNumber, NationalRegistrationNotifyDistributionAddress, NationalRegistrationNotifyPostCode, NationalRegistrationNotifyCity, ForeignDistrubtionAddress1, ForeignDistrubtionAddress2, ForeignDistrubtionAddress3, ForeignDistrubtionCountry, ForeignDate, BirthCountyCode, BirthParish, ForeignBirthCity, CitizenshipCode, CitizenshipDate, Email, Telephone, Mobiletelephone, Gender, NotNewsPaper, Note, StatusCode, NationalRegistrationCode, RegistrationDate, LastUpdatedFromNavet, TemporaryDistrubtionAddress1,TemporaryDistrubtionAddress2, TemporaryDistrubtionAddress3, TemporaryDistrubtionCountry, Password, VisibilityLevel, LastChangedBy, LastChangedDate, SeamanIdentity, Category)", connection);
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonalIdentityNumber", PersonalIdentityNumber);


            command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        connection.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
}
```

}

I get error on the `command1.ExecuteNonQuery();`

The error says

> The name "NationalRegistrationNotifyDistributionAddress" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

Why do I get that error?
The XML `navetout.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <ArrayOfFolkbokforingspostTYPE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">   <FolkbokforingspostTYPE>
    <Sekretessmarkering xsi:nil="true" />
    <Personpost>
      <PersonId>
        <PersonNr>194903188953</PersonNr>
      </PersonId>
      <HanvisningsPersonNr xsi:nil="true" />
      <Namn>
        <Tilltalsnamnsmarkering>20</Tilltalsnamnsmarkering>
        <Fornamn>Erik Lennart</Fornamn>
        <Mellannamn xsi:nil="true" />
        <Efternamn>Enberg</Efternamn>
        <Aviseringsnamn xsi:nil="true" />
      </Namn>
      <Folkbokforing>
        <Folkbokforingsdatum>20060512</Folkbokforingsdatum>
        <LanKod>25</LanKod>
        <KommunKod>14</KommunKod>
        <ForsamlingKod xsi:nil="true" />
        <Fastighetsbeteckning>PÅLÄNGE 6:38</Fastighetsbeteckning>
        <FiktivtNr>0</FiktivtNr>
      </Folkbokforing>
      <Adresser>
        <Folkbokforingsadress>
          <CareOf xsi:nil="true" />
          <Utdelningsadress1 xsi:nil="true" />
          <Utdelningsadress2>STORVÄGEN 65</Utdelningsadress2>
          <PostNr>95204</PostNr>
          <Postort>PÅLÄNG</Postort>
        </Folkbokforingsadress>
        <Riksnycklar>
          <FastighetsId>250015520</FastighetsId>
          <AdressplatsId>2416233</AdressplatsId>
          <LagenhetsId>22143838</LagenhetsId>
        </Riksnycklar>
      </Adresser>
      <Fodelse>
        <HemortSverige>
          <FodelselanKod>25</FodelselanKod>
          <Fodelseforsamling>NEDERKALIX</Fodelseforsamling>
        </HemortSverige>
      </Fodelse>
      <Medborgarskap>
        <MedborgarskapslandKod>SE</MedborgarskapslandKod>
        <Medborgarskapsdatum>0</Medborgarskapsdatum>
      </Medborgarskap>
    </Personpost>   </FolkbokforingspostTYPE>   <FolkbokforingspostTYPE>
    <Sekretessmarkering xsi:nil="true" />
    <Personpost>
      <PersonId>
    <TilldelatPersonNrSamordningsNr>195405869370</TilldelatPersonNrSamordningsNr>
      </PersonId>
      <HanvisningsPersonNr xsi:nil="true" />
      <Namn>
        <Fornamn styrkt="J">Eduardo Metran</Fornamn>
        <Mellannamn xsi:nil="true" />
        <Efternamn styrkt="J">Garcia</Efternamn>
        <Aviseringsnamn xsi:nil="true" />
      </Namn>
      <Folkbokforing>
        <Folkbokforingsdatum xsi:nil="true" />
        <LanKod>14</LanKod>
        <KommunKod xsi:nil="true" />
        <ForsamlingKod xsi:nil="true" />
        <Fastighetsbeteckning xsi:nil="true" />
      </Folkbokforing>
      <Adresser />
      <Fodelse>
        <OrtUtlandet>
          <FodelseortUtland styrkt="J">Sta Cruz Zambales</FodelseortUtland>
          <Fodelseland>FILIPPINERNA</Fodelseland>
        </OrtUtlandet>
      </Fodelse>
      <Medborgarskap>
        <MedborgarskapslandKod styrkt="J">PH</MedborgarskapslandKod>
        <Medborgarskapsdatum>0</Medborgarskapsdatum>
      </Medborgarskap>
    </Personpost>   </FolkbokforingspostTYPE> </ArrayOfFolkbokforingspostTYPE>
```

Why do I get the error?

And most importantly, how can I "translate" the XML-tags to match the table columns?

Comment: You haven;t told it what column the value lines up with in the `INSERT` statement..

Comment: Do you mean this? `command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonalIdentityNumber", PersonalIdentityNumber);`
If not, could you give an example, because I don't quite understand.

Comment: `INSERT INTO Seamen ({column name goes here}) values (@PersonalIdentityNumber)`  The `INSERT` will not infer the column you are inserting based on the parameter name.  Also I suspect you will be inserting _several_ values instead of just one - otherwise what's the point of having 40+ local variables?

Comment: @DStanley Yes, I will insert all the local variables, I just wanted to try one first to see if was working. Will the XML-tags match with the column names? Because they do have different names. For example, the column `PersonalIdentityNumber` is supposed to match the the XML tag `PersonNr`

Comment: You mean will the SQL magically know what column you want the values to line up with when you insert?  No, you have to explicitly state the columns that line up with the values.

Comment: How do I do that? ..